# Querying matching names from a chunk of text using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I am wanting to run a query which will pull out of a database any names that match from a chunk of text.

My table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `Names` (
  `NameId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Names` (`NameId`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 'Tom Thumb'),
(2, 'Peter Pan'),
(3, 'David Bowie'),
(4, 'Mick Jagger'),
(5, 'Ronnie Wood'),
(6, 'Charlie Watts'),
(7, 'Keith Richards'),
(8, 'Brian May');
```

So, if the text below was passed, records 4,5,6,7 would be returned.

> The Rolling Stones are a legendary British rock band formed in 1962.
> Known for their enduring influence and iconic hits, they consist of
> Mick Jagger (vocals), Keith Richards (guitar), Charlie Watts (drums),
> Ronnie Wood (guitar), and past members like Brian Jones and Bill
> Wyman. With a dynamic blend of rock, blues, and rhythm and blues, the
> Stones have sold over 200 million records worldwide. Their music spans
> decades, featuring timeless classics like "Paint It Black," "(I Can't
> Get No) Satisfaction," and "Angie." Renowned for their electrifying
> live performances, the Rolling Stones remain one of the greatest rock
> acts in history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT `Name`
FROM `Names`
WHERE
  'The Rolling Stones are a legendary British rock band formed in 1962. Known for their enduring influence and iconic hits, they consist of Mick Jagger (vocals), Keith Richards (guitar), Charlie Watts (drums), Ronnie Wood (guitar), and past members like Brian Jones and Bill Wyman. With a dynamic blend of rock, blues, and rhythm and blues, the Stones have sold over 200 million records worldwide. Their music spans decades, featuring timeless classics like "Paint It Black," "(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction," and "Angie." Renowned for their electrifying live performances, the Rolling Stones remain one of the greatest rock acts in history.'
  LIKE CONCAT('%', `Name`, '%');
```

Should return

```
+----------------+
|      Name      |
+----------------+
| Mick Jagger    |
| Keith Richards |
| Charlie Watts  |
| Ronnie Wood    |
| Brian May      |
+----------------+
```

Edit: Please make note of the quotation. If you have quotes inside of your text, it is best to escape them (`\'`), or use one type of quotes inside of the text and another type of quotes outside of the text (i.e. `"Hello 'world'."`).

Comment: That is fine for a limited number of names and limited size of text.  For scaling, you may need a `FULLTEXT` index on the incoming string.

Comment: @RickJames That is true. It is done with `MATCH x AGAINST y` if I am not mistaken? If it is so, you can add your own answer or edit mine, whichever you prefer.